How to hide being inside of a magical zone to Detect Magic
My group is on a quest to find a wizard's spellbook, hidden in the place where the wizard secluded himself 30 years ago. During the campaign, the party has come to suspect that the wizard might still be alive in the cave, as he's been described as extremely powerful, this is, of course, nothing more than just a theory, as the wizard is in fact dead.
My concept for the cave is that the wizard set up a magical illusion to make it appear cozy and welcoming, tempting anyone who enters to stay. He also created a modified simulacrum as a guardian to protect the spellbook. This simulacrum's role is to test anyone who reaches the cave while maintaining the illusion.
I'm not too worried about the specific mechanics of how the cave's magic works, as I have time to refine that (though I'm open to suggestions). My main challenge right now is handling the group's bard, who loves to cast Detect Magic. I want to prevent them from instantly realizing they're inside an illusion, as part of the test to receive the spellbook is recognizing that the illusion and the wizard's 'presence' aren't real. Detect Magic feels like a shortcut that could spoil that reveal. Any advice on managing this?

5e 2014 and 2024 are different games with different rules. We need to know which you are playing.

Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum
The Sanctum can be made permanent and covers a wide area, one of its possible effects is:

Creatures in the area can't be targeted by Divination spells.

Detect Magic is a divination spell that targets self, so it doesn't work for anyone within the Sanctum. The Sanctum should extend 30 feet beyond the illusion, so that the illusion also can't be detected by someone outside the Sanctum.
What's more, it's entirely reasonable for a secluded wizard to ward their abode with Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum.

Good find. That's a much better suggestion than my own answer.

Modified Nystul's Magic Aura
Nystul's Magic Aura sounds like what you want, but it won't work out of the box. The reason is that it targets a creature or an object, and an illusion is neither. But you could use that spell as a base to say that the wizard could have masked the illusion using magic. In my mind it makes sense that powerful NPC wizards aren't restricted to only the spell options in the PHB.

Using Wish to make the aura suppression permanent, apply to the entire cave (is a single caverns a single object?), or both is well within the parameters of Wish. No home brew required.

The question is tagged with two different editions and doesn’t specify which. Please at least specify which edition your answer refers to if you are going to answer ambiguous questions.

@ThomasMarkov You're completely right! I also notice that the 2014 version cannot affect magical effects so it can't conceal the illusion.

Thank you, im aware of that both editions have different rules, my group is in the middle of going from 2014 to 2024 but some rules we rather keep the ones from 2014 so that's why i left that tag, and thanks for the spell, i dont know how could i miss that, 2014 DMG did say different versions of a spell could exist so i definitely could use one that can recognize the cave as an object

I was apparently confused and thought the 2024 version could target magical effects. It can not. The change from 2014 was that it affects magical effects trying to discern the nature of the spell's target. You're still limited to an object or a creature as targets, and an illusion is neither.

@Agustin If you do need to know how it works in each ruleset, you can leave both tags, but we just need that explained in the question. That is pertinent information about what you’re asking.

@JoakimM.H. i see, i guess i ill have to take the Wish approach for the illusion concealing, but your answer still gave me a solution to how can i prevent them from realizing the Simulacrum is not the real wizard, as the Mask feature would allow me to make him appear as a regular person instead of a construct, so thank you very much :D

@ThomasMarkov i'll take it into account for the next questions i ask, im new to the website so i didnt know it could come through as confusing when listing both editions w/o clarification, sorry for the confusion and thanks for your patience :)
